# Cassandra is not starting due to accessdeniedexception

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, cql, cassandra-node-driver

I keep getting the following error when attempting to start Cassandra:

> WARN  [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2019-09-23 20:52:14,452
>   LogReplicaSet.java:220 - Failed to add record to a replica:
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   /data/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc_txn_flush_05936940-de44-11e9-9dfb-251fcce05198.log
>   ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2019-09-23 20:52:14,457
>   ColumnFamilyStore.java:1183 - Flushing
>   Memtable-local@1437882581(0.334KiB serialized bytes, 2 ops, 0%/0% of
>   on/off-heap limit) failed with error java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   /data/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc_txn_flush_05936940-de44-11e9-9dfb-251fcce05198.log

Comment: `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` looks like a permission problem on the file/folder

Comment: How to I change the permission? @maelig

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/modify-file-permissions-with-chmod/

Comment: I guess specifically which directory? The data/Cassandra/data/system? @Maelig

Comment: Don't know, just try :)

Comment: yeah it didnt work...any other ideas? thank you in advance @Maelig

Comment: no more ideas :/

Answer (score 1):

I had same situation after dropping a materialized view. Look for directory permissions. You will see that directory and `schema.cql` will have `root` ownerability.

```sh
$ ls -la /data/cassandra/data/<keyspace>/<keyspace>-6d7291801cd811ea84aedd85165df9d2/snapshots/analyse-LFDBFUZCMGCMGKHFYAFW/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root      root             4096 Mar 26 19:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 cassandra cassandra      241664 Mar 27 03:11 ..
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra          92 Mar 26 13:46 md-7426-big-TOC.txt
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra        2435 Mar 26 14:29 md-7427-big-CompressionInfo.db
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra    12025128 Mar 26 14:29 md-7427-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra          10 Mar 26 14:29 md-7427-big-Digest.crc32
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra       66056 Mar 26 14:29 md-7427-big-Filter.db
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra     1573654 Mar 26 14:29 md-7427-big-Index.db
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra       10869 Mar 26 14:29 md-7427-big-Statistics.db
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra       16568 Mar 26 14:29 md-7427-big-Summary.db
-rw-r--r-- 2 cassandra cassandra          92 Mar 26 14:29 md-7427-big-TOC.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root              962 Mar 26 19:58 schema.cql
...
```

You can fix by making file and folder owners `cassandra`:

```sh
$ chown -R cassandra:cassandra /data/cassandra/data/<keyspace>/<keyspace>-6d7291801cd811ea84aedd85165df9d2/snapshots/analyse-LFDBFUZCMGCMGKHFYAFW/
```